How can I avoid first row being deleted in this simple EntireRow.Delete VBA code?
I am using the simple code below to remove unwanted rows.  It works very well but I cannot avoid the first row being deleted, regardless of whether it meets the criterion for deletion.  There is an unanswered question out there with some things to try (I tried those), but no solution, so I think that success with my question will also help others.
Sub DeleteCertainRows()

Dim lr As Long
lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    With Range("E1:E" & lr)
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">2"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub


First suggestion hid data and second one deleted everything.  Thanks anyway

.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete   Might need to wrap that in On Error Resume Next and On Error Goto 0 to handle the case where there are no visible rows.

This should do it:
Sub DeleteCertainRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    With ws.Range("E1:E" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">2"
        On Error Resume Next 'in case there are no visible rows...
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        On Error Goto 0      'stop ignoring errors
    End With
End Sub


Answered by Tim Williams and posted here to help others.
On Error Resume Next and On Error Goto 0 were not needed in my case.

Sub DeleteCertainRows()
    
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    With Range("E1:E" & lr)
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">2"
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub



Delete Range Rows
Usage
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    DeleteRangeRowsByCriterion rg, 5, ">2", True

End Sub


Helper Method
Sub DeleteRangeRowsByCriterion( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal Field As Long, _
        ByVal Criteria1 As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal IsInTestMode As Boolean = False)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Range Rows By Criterion"
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rg.Worksheet
    
    ' Store the number of data rows in a variable.
    Dim DataRowsCount As Long: DataRowsCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1
    
    ' Validate the number of data rows.
    If DataRowsCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The range ""'" & ws.Name & "'!" & rg.Address(0, 0) _
            & """ has only one row!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Validate the column index.
    If Field < 1 Then
        MsgBox "The column index (" & Field & ") is too small!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Field > rg.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox "The column index (" & Field & ") is too big for the range " _
            & """'" & ws.Name & "'!" & rg.Address(0, 0) & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Store the AutoFilterMode state in a variable.
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData ' clear filters
    Dim WasAutoFiltered As Boolean: WasAutoFiltered = ws.AutoFilterMode
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off auto-filtering
    
    ' Reference the data range (no headers).
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(DataRowsCount).Offset(1)
    Dim drgAddress As String:
    drgAddress = "'" & ws.Name & "'!" & drg.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' Filter the range (has headers).
    rg.AutoFilter Field:=Field, Criteria1:=Criteria1
    
    ' Reference the filtered data rows.
    Dim fdrg As Range:
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error handling (ignore errors)
        Set fdrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' restart error-handling routine
    
    ' Restore AutoFilterMode state.
    If WasAutoFiltered Then
        ws.ShowAllData
    Else
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    ' Check if no filtered rows.
    If fdrg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching rows found in """ & drgAddress & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Store the number of filtered rows in a variable.
    Dim FilteredRowsCount As Long
    FilteredRowsCount = Intersect(fdrg, drg.Columns(1)).Cells.Count
    
    ' Delete or select the filtered rows.
    If IsInTestMode Then
        Application.Goto Reference:=fdrg
    Else
        fdrg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End If
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox IIf(IsInTestMode, "Running in Test Mode!" & vbLf & vbLf, "") _
        & IIf(IsInTestMode, "Selected", "Deleted") & " " & FilteredRowsCount _
        & " row" & IIf(FilteredRowsCount = 1, "", "s") & " in """ _
        & drgAddress & """!", _
        IIf(IsInTestMode, vbExclamation, vbInformation), PROC_TITLE
        
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

